# How do I get ALL items and filter queried items when using Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have the following Array:

```
const cars = [
  { make: 'Toyota', model: '4Runner', bodyType: 'SUV' },
  { make: 'Audi', model: 'A4', bodyType: 'Sedan' },
  { make: 'Ford', model: 'F-150', bodyType: 'Truck' },
]
```

I would like to send the cars array when visiting /cars endpoint. But when the user adds a query to the endpoint such as /cars?bodyType=SUV it should only return the filtered items.

So far I have:

```
app.get('/cars', (req, res) => {
  const bodyType = req.query.bodyType
  const filteredCars = cars.filter((car) => car.bodyType === bodyType)
  res.send(req.query ===  ? cars : filteredCars)
})
```

I know i'm probably way off.

Comment: Can you have mulipe queries? For eg: /cars?bodyType=SUV&model=A4
Or will you always have only one query

Comment: right now i'm only working with one, but i'm open to learning about more @adhinarayan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code works loops through all the keys in the query and compares it with the car object.

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  const filter = req.query
  const haveFilters = Object.keys(filter).length
  let filteredCars = cars
  if(haveFilters){
    filteredCars = cars.filter((car) => {
      for(let key in filter){
        if(car[key] !== filter[key]) return false
      }
      return true
    })
  }

  res.send(filteredCars)
})
```

Comment: I think you forgot the res.send() otherwise it gives an error

Comment: req.query would resolve to true as it would return an empty object even if there are no queries. You might need to check with the length.

Comment: I had to remove the if statement. With the if statement in place in creates an error saying:  "ReferenceError: filteredCars is not defined" otherwise it works as intended.

Comment: Oh, Yes. const is block scoped. you can solve it by declaring filteredCars using a var instead of const or declaring the variable outside the if statement

Comment: if you change it in your answer I can mark it solved! thanks!

Comment: I have edited the code. I believe it should work now.